# What is the name of this part

Tags: part-identification, city

This part is usually used on the simple 4 wide car base mostly seen in city sets.
With making these simple cars, it sits on the sides, and provides a base under a 1x4 Panel pieces. 4 studs on the lower part, 1 higher stud on each side which touches with the fender pieces. Dimensions for this piece is **1x6x1**.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

BrickLink calls it **[Part 52501 Slope, Inverted 45 6 x 1 Double with 1 x 4 Cutout](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=52501#T=C)**:

[image: part]